# RequireJS not finding modules in webjars

Tags: spring-boot, requirejs, webjars

I am developing a web app using Maven, Spring Boot, WebJars and RequireJS. I have an issue with RequireJS not finding some of the JavaScript modules. I have successfully configured Spring Boot and RequireJS and 7 of the 9 modules load correctly the two that don't load are: crossroads and requirejs-i18n.

I have include both web jars in my pom like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>requirejs-i18n</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>crossroads.js</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my own modules I try to load crossroads and requirejs-i18n as dependencies like this:

```
define(['jquery',
    'signals',
    'Hasher',
    'crossroads'], function ($, signals, hasher, crossroads) {...
```

In this example, jquery, signals and Hasher load but crossroads does not and I see this in my browser console:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source http://localhost:8080/js/crossroads.js.js
```

When I try to load requirejs-i18n I see this:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source http://localhost:8080/js/requirejs-i18n.js
```

Other modules load fine like this:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/webjars/Hasher/1.2.0/hasher.js
```

Any ideas?

I managed to fix the issue with crossroads by changing the maven dependency from

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
   <artifactId>crossroads.js</artifactId>
   <version>0.12.0-1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
   <artifactId>crossroads</artifactId>
   <version>0.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```

requirejs-i18n still does not load, I have tried using it like this:

```
define(['i18n!nls/messages'], function(messages){
```

and this

```
define(['requirejs-i18n!nls/messages'], function(messages){
```

Comment: I have managed to successfully load crossroads by changing my maven dependency but requirejs-i18n does not load

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed this issue by doing this;

```
require.config({
   paths: {
      'i18n' : '/webjars/requirejs-i18n/i18n',
   }
});
```

But I'm not sure if this is the correct solution

Comment: Usually the requirejs config can be generated automatically.  Are you using that part of `webjars-locator` https://javadoccentral.herokuapp.com/org.webjars/webjars-locator/0.32-1/org/webjars/RequireJS.html

Comment: Hi James, I am using the webjars-locator but only the getSetupJavaScript method. There are other methods in org.webjars.RequireJS that may help. I'll try and figure it out. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: In the generated RequireJS config, do you see the config for `i18n` ?

Comment: Hi James, the RequireJS config has a webjars.version for i18n but it does not have a requirejs.config statement for i18n

Comment: I think the requirejs.config is dynamically generated from the webjars.version.  So it seems this should have worked.  Would you mind filing a bug: https://github.com/webjars/webjars-locator/issues

Comment: Hi James, I just created the bug. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "i18n": webjars.path("requirejs-i18n", "i18n")
    }
});
```